# Unresolved name error when using std::ptr::set_memory

Tags: rust

I'm using `ptr::set_memory` from [the std module](http://smallcultfollowing.com/rust-int-variations/imem-umem/std/ptr/fn.set_memory.html):

```
use std::ptr;

fn main() {
    let addr = 0 as *mut u8;
    unsafe { ptr::set_memory(addr, 0, 8); }
}
```

But the program won't compile due to this error:

```
src/main.rs:160:18: 160:33 error: unresolved name `ptr::set_memory` [E0425]
src/main.rs:160         unsafe { ptr::set_memory(p, 0, total_size); }
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Neither can we, if you don't show your code. Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @starblue fair enough, it seems to happen with any use of the function though. Have edited to show a new project which only uses the problem call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation you found is for a rather old version of Rust. In the current version you could use [`std::ptr::write_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.write_bytes.html)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are accidentally using outdated, unofficial documentation. `ptr::set_memory` is not part of `std`. Use [the official documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/).